# sass classes for colorizing in html

Tags: html, css, sass

i would like to create sass classes, such as .blue and .bg, 
but depending on which i use, it should colorize the fonts and/or the background.

```
// Classes for colorizing elements

.blue {
  color: $primary-color;
  &.bg {
    background-color: $primary-color;
    color: initial;
  }
}

.light-gray {
  color: $light-gray;
  &.bg {
    background-color: $light-gray;
    color: initial;
  }
}

.medium-gray {
  color: $medium-gray;
  &.bg {
    background-color: $medium-gray;
    color: initial;
  }
}

.dark-gray {
  color: $dark-gray;
  &.bg {
    background-color: $dark-gray;
    color: initial;
  }
}

.black {
  color: $black;
  &.bg {
    background-color: $black;
    color: initial;
  }
}

.white {
  color: $white;
  &.bg {
    background-color: $white;
    color: initial;
  }
}
```

the use of `color:inherit` here is repetitive and inefficient.

for example, if I use `.black .bg` than ONLY the background-color should be black.

If I only use `.black`, than ONLY the font-color should be used.

`.bg` alone doesn't have to work in this case

Which SCSS/SASS elements can i use to achieve small and efficient code?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Anything at all?

Comment: yes? or do you mean the first answer?

Comment: You haven't shown that you've tried anything before asking this question, it's just a "write code for me" request.  We don't do that here.  Put some effort into solving your problem.  Have you given any thought at all as to what the output should be?

Comment: well I think you are wrong. i asked for a SASS function i could use to improve my code. the suggested mixin ends up with heavier code, so i won't use it. i did not ask for ready solutions, just for the function name, which would lead me to the right chapter in the docs

Comment: We don't do "suggestions" or "hints" here, either.  The Sass docs are a single page, you can read them yourself.

Comment: which i did, but in my limited capabilities i couldn't find the desired function. thats why i asked for a little help, not for a pointless discussion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i understand your question, If i do here is what i'd do:

```
$blue: blue;
$light-grey: white-smoke;
$medium-grey: grey;

$colorList: blue, light-grey, medium-grey;
$colorListVar: $blue, $light-grey, $medium-grey;


@for $i from 1 through length($colorList) {
    .#{nth($colorList, $i)} {
        color: nth($colorListVar, $i);
        &.bg {
            color: initial;
            background: nth($colorListVar, $i); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that it exactly what i was looking for, thank you very much!

Comment: no problem, feel free to up-vote!

Answer (score -1):

Write a mixin. It should be something like:

```
@mixin color($color, $bg) {
  @if $bg == "true" {
   color: $color;
 } @else if $bg == "false" {
   color: initial;
   background-color: $color;
 } 
}

.blue{
  @include color(blue, true);
  &.bg {
     @include color(blue, false);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the issue is more related to how to structure the classes and names to get the desired effect then how to write a mixin...

Comment: looks promising, but i would end up writing more code than in my post above